# Laravel 5 Eloquent Ищу способ оптимизировать код

Tags: база-данных, laravel, model, php-frameworks, eloquent

Ищу способ оптимизировать данный код:

```
    /* Get customers/providers id*/
    $contr_id = explode(', ', $request->contr_id);
    $prov_id = explode(', ', $request->prov_id);
    $count = count($contr_id);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

        $contr_proj = new Contr_Project();
        $contr_proj->proj_id = $project->id;
        $contr_proj->contr_id = $contr_id[$i];
        $contr_proj->save();
    }

    $count = count($prov_id);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

        $prov_proj = new Prov_Project();
        $prov_proj->proj_id = $project->id;
        $prov_proj->prov_id = $prov_id[$i];
        $prov_proj->save();
    }
```

Выглядит он довольно некрасиво, мне кажется что в laravel 5 есть способ сделать добавление в БД, не используя такие циклы. Суть в том, что для таблиц `proj_id` у нас одинаков, а вот `contr_id` и `prov_id` разный. Поэтому, я решил использовать циклы.

Структура таблиц:

Таблица - prov_proj(
id,
proj_id,
prov_id)

Таблица - contr_proj(id,
proj_id,
contr_id)

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ это сделать без циклов и если есть, то какой?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос описание полей таблиц и связей между таблицами. `cust_id` у вас в вопросе отсутствует.

Comment: @VenZell Извините, я ошибся, там нет cust_id, там proj_id. Исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я поняла здесь написана попытка связать модели proj и prov и модели proj и contr. В laravel для создания связи многие-ко-многим есть стандартный функционал:

```
class Proj {
   public function prov()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prov', 'prov_proj')->withPivot(доп. параметры связи);
   }
}

class Prov {
  public function proj()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Proj', 'prov_proj');
  }
}
```

И тогда добавление связи выглядит так

```
$proj->attach($prov_ids)
```

И вообще по хорошему передавать id-шки нужно не строкой, а сразу массивом.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)